# argument of type '..' does not match '..' C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, types, arguments

C++ in eclipse gives the following error and i can't find out why:
..\BakeryC++\src\controller\controller.cpp:227:20: error: argument of type 'std::string (Repository::)()const {aka std::basic_string (Repository::)()const}' does not match 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}'

My function header looks like this:

```
virtual string getAsText(Product* p) = 0;
```

It's inherited in other modules, but the function where i call it sees only this header.
The function looks like:

```
string Controller::toString() const{
    return rep->toString;
}
```

Just to be sure, here's the original toString() function:

```
string IMRepository::toString() const
{
    string str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < this->getSize(); i++)
    {
        Product* p = this->ProductList.get(i);
        if (p == NULL)
            continue;

        string name(p->getName());
        string supplier(p->getSupplier());
        char quantity[3];
        sprintf(quantity, "%d", p->getQuantity());
        string sq(quantity);
        str+=name+", "+supplier+", "+sq+"\n";
    }
    return str;
}
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: That's a horrible error message. What compiler/version are you using inside eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the important message in that error.

```
std::basic_string (Repository::)() const does not match std::string
```

You are returning a *function pointer* instead of *the result of a function call*.

Change this

```
return rep->toString;
```

To this.

```
return rep->toString();
```

Comment: oh, thanks, didn't notice that

Answer (score 3):

`getAsText` should be `const` if you are calling it from a `const` function, although i don't see you using it anywhere, i suppose you actually do (or maybe you meant `toString`).

Also, you are returning a pointer on the `toString` function instead of the result of the call. You need to add a pair of braces in `Controller::toString()`.